# Wpf - How to Row Edit End programmatically after Specific Cell Edit Ended

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm, telerik-grid

I have "Product" Textbox where the user type Product Name. When the user press enter, this "Product" will be added to the GridView and auto-focus to "Quantity "cell. (I've successfully developed this part.)

After the user type Quantity in GridView's Cell, I want to CommitEdit to this row and focus return back to "Product" textbox. This is the part that I don't know how to do it.

Currently I have tried something like the following:

```
private void RadGridViewInvoiceItems_CellEditEnded( object sender, GridViewCellEditEndedEventArgs e )
{
      if ( e.Cell.Column.Header.ToString() == "Quantity" )
      {
           this.gridView.CommitEdit();
           this.productTextBox.Focus();
      }         
}
```

But the above code cause "StackOverFlow" exception. How should I solve this problem?

P.S. I have developed this app with C# Wpf with MVVM pattern and Telerik controls.

Comment: Can wee see the code from your ViewModel ......

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataGrid.CommitEdit from your DataGrid.CellEditEnding handler, being sure to handle reentrancy.

Here's a blog article that describes the technique:

- http://codefluff.blogspot.de/2010/05/commiting-bound-cell-changes.html